# JavaFX Filter MySQL Result Set as Typing

Tags: java, mysql, javafx

I have a list of employees in a MySQL database that I have displayed in a JavaFX TableView. What I would like to do is allow the user to select the employee they are currently completing a task for.

What I could do is get the user to enter their name in a search box, then filter the result set using `SELECT * FROM 'Employees' WHERE Name = 'userinput';` after the user has clicked the search button.

What I would much prefer is to filter the table WHILST the user is typing. So for example if they were searching for an employee named 'John Smith', after they have typed 'Joh' then the table will be filtered by `WHERE Name = 'Joh'` and so on.

Is there a way of doing this in JavaFX / MySQL?

Comment: If you can retrieve all the data from the database, just do the filtering directly in the `TableView`, using a [`FilteredList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/transformation/FilteredList.html). Read a tutorial, e.g. http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-8-tableview-sorting-filtering/ and try it, post a specific question if you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

why not try 
select firstname, lastname from persontable where firstname like 'Joh%';

You can convert firstname and your search string to the lower or upper case (I mean to the same case. like '%Joh%'will select records where JOH appears even if this pattern appears in the middle.